EF Core change tracking and Blazor Server
I'm struggling to find a good pattern to work with EF Core and Blazor Server.
From my research, the best thing to do is using DI and DbContextFactory. Then wrap every operation in its own DbContext.
Program.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>();
}

OrderService.cs:
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;

public OrderService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
}

public async Task<Order[]> GetAllOrders()
{
    using var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    return await _context.Orders.Include(o=>o.OrderLines).ToArrayAsync();
}

But the problem with this, is the DbContext will be disposed, and I'll lose any change tracking abilities.
For example if the data is tied to an editable DataTable.
If lots of of the orders are edited, I can't just do context.SaveChanges() when a user hits "Save" and have EF Core only update the fields that have changed.
@inject OrderService _orderSerivce;

void DoTest()
{
    var orders =_orderSerivce.GetAllOrders(); // Gets 500 orders 

    Random r = new Random();

    // edit upto 20 orders. 
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       int rInt = r.Next(0, orders.Length-1);
       orders[rInt].CustomerName = "NameChanged " + i;
    }

    _orderSerivce.UpdateOrders(orders); // ?? What should this do
}

I'm not sure how the UpdateOrders function should work?
Should I just attach the orders and let it update all 500 orders. SaveChanges would have tracked what was edited and what is new and handle it all for me. E.g.
public async Task UpdateOrders(Order[] orders)
{
    // Use a new context instance to perform the updates
    using var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    
    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        // Attach each order to the context and mark it as modified
        ctx.Orders.Attach(order);
        ctx.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    // Save all changes to the database
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}

But with the disposed context, how do I now extract only the changes to update?

The question is a bit unclear. You don't need to wrap anything in a DbContext, even if such a thing was possible. A DbContext, no matter the application, is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work which means it's only meant to live for the duration of the specific business process/use-case/transaction. When you dispose of it, you're effectively cancelling all those changes. If you want to persist the changes, at the very end of the process you call SaveChanges once to persist all changes at once.

There's no need for a GetAllOrders either, in fact that's a huge red flag. You never want to load an entire table in memory. And that UpdateOrders isn't needed at all - a DbContext already knows which entities have changed so nothing more than SaveChanges is needed

Keep track of modified entities in the service or directly within your Blazor component. You could store an Order reference when it's edited, keeping track of only the modified orders. In your UpdateOrders method, attach only modified entities to the new context. EF Core will recognize them as modified without reloading all the data.

@Salt why? DbContext already does that. That's exactly what it is for. No UpdateOrders is needed or any kind of external tracking

@PanagiotisKanavos You're right that DbContext already handles change tracking effectively, and EF Core will track only modified properties if the entities are kept within the same context. The main issue here is that with a disconnected context you’re losing change tracking as each method call involves a new DbContext instance. This is why the service doesn't automatically "remember" changes across different method calls.

This OrderService looks like a common anti-pattern: a single-entity low-level CRUD class wrapped over a high-level multi-entity Unit-of-Work. Try removing it completely and just use DbContextFactory as shown in the docs - create the instance at the start of DoTest, or wherever you consider the transaction to start, load and modify the objects and only at the end call SaveChanges before desposing the DbContext. Only try to create abstractions after you get that working

@Salt a DbContext is always disconnected and doesn't lose change tracking. The code was copied from some article or "best practices" blog post and is simply wrong and a sign of a bad practice. A DbContext isn't a database connection and doesn't keep one open between reading and saving

@PanagiotisKanavos but save changes will fail, as the DBContext will be disposed of due the the using wrap around within GetAllOrders

@PanagiotisKanavos I do agree on the anti pattern, but in reality, if someone's searching / sorting an order table, it's substantially quicker to load the whole order table into memory, then any calculated fields etc don't need to be revaluated on every sort / filter operation

Loading 100K rows in memory before searching isn't quicker. You're confusing caching with loading

@JamesWilliams - take a look at QuickGrid and its EF adapter. That solves the many rows problem, but you do have to manage the lifetime of a DbCtx. Which you will end up doing Blazor server-side one way or another when you want to use tracking. Next step is a REST API that you can use from Auto & Wasm. Detached DTOs all the way.
